# Shell script to become root

Tags: shell, shell-script, password, root, su

How can we write a shell script to become root?
That is I donot want to input the password at prompt it should be within the script itself. I was trying to make but failed to do so.Is it possible, if Yes please Explain.

Comment: Does it need to be a shell script? I don't see how that would be possible, but you could set it up so `sudo su` or `sudo bash` works without a password

Comment: @MichaelMrozek `sudo -i` is preferred. It requires permissions to run `sudo bash`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a script using [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) tool.

In Redhat, expect package comes by default. But in Ubuntu you need to install it separately.

You can check this by using commands:

`$ rpm -qa | grep expect`     for Redhat

`$ dpkg -l expect` for Ubuntu

The following script will do your work:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn su -
expect "Password: "
send "password\r"
interact
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing the cleartext of the root password in a file is **inherently dangerous** - there are lots of routes by which it can be recovered.

This appears to be an XY problem.

The unixy way of delegating permissions is via the setuid bit - but this can only be applied to binary executables, not shell scripts. As jordanm states, applying setuid to the shell itself is very dangerous - that's why sudo exists - it has a setuid bit and validates user requests against the sudoers file to give a fine-grained control over access. But sudo also has some gotchas.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is to make a suid copy of the shell:

```
cp /bin/bash $HOME/bin/becomeroot
sudo chown root $HOME/bin/becomeroot
sudo chmod 4750 $HOME/bin/becomeroot
hash -r
```

Then, running `becomeroot` will start a bash subshell running as root.

However, I would be remiss if I didn't give you this advice: don't do that. It's unwise to make it so easy for malware to escalate its privileges to root. Instead, just install `sudo` and learn to use it whenever you need to run something as root.

Answer (score -2):

You can set the SUID sticky bit:

```
chmod 2664 your-file
```

That will cause the software to run as the owner of the file.  So of course, you'll have to change ownership to root:

```
sudo chown root your-file
```

(assuming you are found in the sudoers file, and you've installed sudo)

Comment: setuid does not work on shell scripts unless you setuid the shell binary (not recommended).